# MySQL SELECT com ORDER BY no GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, order-by

Tenho uma tabela chamada **contatos**, nela é cadastrado todos os contatos feitos no site. Existe também uma tabela chamada **status**, onde é armazenado o status de atendimento de cada **contato**.

A dúvida, preciso dar um SELECT nos contatos, e no LEFT JOIN mostrar apenas o último status gravado na tabela **status**. Fiz dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM contato
LEFT JOIN status ON status.id_contato = contato.id
GROUP BY status.id_contato
ORDER BY contato.dia DESC
```

O problema nessa consulta é que com o GROUP BY ele acaba mostrando apenas o primeiro status e não o último. Como agrupar e depois mostrar o último (com ID maior e mais atual)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sei se a tabela `status` tem um campo `id`; caso tenha, segue

```
SELECT c.*, q.maxid
FROM contato c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT s.id_contato, MAX(s.id) as maxid
           FROM status s
           GROUP BY s.id_contato) q ON q.id_contato = c.id
ORDER BY c.dia DESC
```